# Pass Japanese Characters to a SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, unicode

I'm trying to pass Japanese characters to a stored procedure in SQL Server. The characters get converted to ???? during execution and hence I get incoreect results.

How do I pass them such characters? I tried using `nvarchar` as its accepts Unicode, but no luck. If I do not use stored procedure and construct the SQL Query string dynamically in my app, things work fine.
Kindly help

**Update**

```
declare @string as nvarchar(1000)
SET @string = @keyword 
SELECT * FROM TABLE where Title like @string
```

Called using

```
EXEC @return_value = StoredProcName 
@keyword = N'Japanese Word'
```

**Update 2**

I would like to add the following if that helps. Constructing the query dynamically works. So if in your app you were to write
sql = "select * from TABLE where Title like '"+[JapaneseWord]+"'"; 
it works. I am unable to determine where the Unicode is failing for a stored proc

**Solution**

NVARCHAR is the key to the problem. In case anyone is interested is knowing how to use it to form a freetext search string, here you go

`declare @string as nvarchar(100) 
set @string = 'FORMSOF(INLFLECTIONAL,"'+@string+'"))'`


Then use it in your query. Like
 `select * from TABLE as TEMP INNERJOIN CONTAINSTABLE(#,#,@string) ......`

 Refer MSDN or relevant docs

Comment: Would it be possible to add the TSQL in your stored procedure?  Would it be as simple as the variable that sends it in does not support unicode?  Or perhaps the variable the returns the result?

Comment: Is your stored procedure's input parameter(s) of type nvarchar, and are you sure it's not being (implicitly) converted to non-Unicode (varchar) at any point in the procedure?

Comment: So - again - **what** doesn't work?? You're not getting back anything? You're getting back the wrong info?? What is your table structure like?? Is the `Title` column in your table `NVARCHAR`, too??

Comment: Can you show the **complete** stored procedure - also its declaration (of the parameters and all) ??? Also: why are you taking in the `@keyword NVARCHAR` and copying it around?? Why not just use `SELECT ... FROM dbo.Table WHERE Title LIKE @keyword` ?? Any particular reason??

Comment: I am doing a free text search so.. I use string to construct the query CONTAINSTABLE(.....). That is the reason string is present. And I do not get anything back.. basically it says no match found. But if construct the query in the code instead I get match

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You definitely need to use `NVARCHAR` as your data type, and if you run this in SQL server Mgmt Studio or from an "inline" SQL query, you need to make sure to prefix the string literals with a `N'.....'` prefix.

So, your stored proc should look something like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.YourProc  @Param1 NVARCHAR(100)
AS
   SELECT N'Test - [' + @Param1 + N'] - end of test'
```

And then call this using:

```
EXEC dbo.YourProc   N'foo-bar-value'
```

Should yield:

```
Test - [foo-bar-value] - end of test
```

and of course this would be much nicer if I knew how to get some Japanese characters in here.... :-)

**Update:** OK, I've picked some random Cyrillic and Thai characters, which I'm positive require `NVARCHAR`, too - and it would appear to me that it works:

```
EXEC dbo.YourProc   N'Є Ї Љ Њ Ќ Ѝ Ў А Й Ж М Р Б'

Test - [Є Ї Љ Њ Ќ Ѝ Ў А Й Ж М Р Б] - end of test

EXEC dbo.YourProc   N'฿ ᴂ ᴆ ᴌ ᴔ ᴓ ᴙ ᴚ ᴝ ᴭ ᴦ ᴣ ᴟ'

Test - [฿ ᴂ ᴆ ᴌ ᴔ ᴓ ᴙ ᴚ ᴝ ᴭ ᴦ ᴣ ᴟ] - end of test
```

Not sure why this Unicode-based test would work, and why it shouldn't work with Japanese characters....

**Update #2:** thanks for Wikipedia - this is said to mean "Tokyo", in Hiragana - seems to work for me:

```
EXEC dbo.YourProc   N'とうきょう'

Test - [とうきょう] - end of test
```

Comment: How does it "not work" ?? .... have you checked all aspects - `NVARCHAR` type, `N'...'` prefixes??  Can you **show us** your stored proc??

Comment: sorry abt that.. Updated the questions. Thanks a lot marc... please see ques